# How do you make a folder inside a folder in firebase database?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

This is the code to upload a something into Firebase database but how do I make a folder that goes inside the "vehicle" folder for "make"

```
self.ref?.child("Vehicle").childByAutoId().setValue(["Model": self.model.text])
```

Comment: just specify the folder and if doesn't exists, Firebase will automatically create it for you.

Comment: how do i specify a folder? @ChristianAbella

Comment: `.child("Vehicle")` is a container (what I assume you mean by "folder"). It's auto-created when you write data underneath, and auto-deleted when there are no values left.

Comment: I want to make another "container" within it @ChristianAbella

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the 'make folder' after the 'Vehicle' and Firebase will automatically create it for you.

```
self.ref?.child("Vehicle/make").childByAutoId().setValue(["Model": self.model.text])
```

Comment: how do I connect the make to a textfield?

Comment: what do you mean by how do you connect the make to a textfield?

Comment: I wanna name the "Make" folder with what i put in my textfield. Then I want to add items to it

Comment: just declare a string variable that will concatenate the let stringVar = "Vehicle/\\(self.model.text)". Then, use that variable in child(stringVar).